# invokeLater and abstract method() in Java

Tags: java, jpanel

I would like to move my JPanel. But I want to smooth movement, but when I put my method

```
void changeLocationCard()
{
  new Thread() {
    public void runCard() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            });
            pause(500);
            }
        }

}.runCard();
}
```

I have a problem with "is not abstract and does not override abstract method run in Runnable.

Declaration class

public class GamePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {}

Somebody knows why?

Comment: Because you're not overriding run

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new abstract Runnable object within your loop. That is a good place to start looking into your issue. Maybe all you need is to implement the run function? public void run() {}

Comment: I changed runCard() to run() but problem is the same.

Comment: did you also call run() instead of runCard()?

Comment: I don't think you need this line: SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { });

Answer (score 0):

Well the compiler is complaining because the anonymous class you declared here:

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        });
```

is not abstract and doesn't implement the run method.

That said, why are you creating a Thread to call a runCard method?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public void changeLocationCard() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run () {
                        runCard();
                    }
                });
                pause(500);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Or check out `TimerTask` from the Swing-Api for a more API-based approach.